# Writing a C program that calculates average quarterly rainfall for a city?

Tags: c, average, formatted-input

I'm struggling with a program I need to write for class. I need to write a program that reads a city's name from the user and then asks the user to enter the month followed by a comma and then the average rainfall for that month. Here's the task at hand:

> Write a program that reads data from the user about the quarterly
>   rainfall in a certain city and displays it on the screen. Your program
>   must prompt the user the following information:
>
> - The name of the city. You may assume it is at most 50 characters.
> - The months and amount of rainfall received for each month. You may assume, for each month, the user will enter both the month and
>     rainfall received values in one line separated by a comma with the
>     month having a length of three characters.
> - The format of the output in terms of field width and precision.
>
> Your program must then calculate the average rainfall and produce
>   output complying with the following specifications:
>
> - Display the name of the city followed by a blank line.
> - For each monthly rainfall value, display the name of the month left justified in the user specified field width followed by the rainfall
>     for that month displayed right justified formatted using fixed-point
>     notation, with the user specified precision, in a field of 15 spaces
>     wide.
> - Finally follow last month's rainfall with a blank line and then on a separate line display the sentence "Average rainfall: " left justified
>     in the user specified field width followed by the average rainfall
>     right justified in fixed-point notation with the user specified
>     precision and in a field of 15 spaces wide.

Now here's my code so far, I'm struggling to get the code right to let the user enter his own comma, the code compiles and runs, but it won't print the next month's line, after hitting enter after entering the first month's details, it just leaves a blank line:

```
int main () 
{

    char cityName[50];
    char monthName[3];
    char comma;
    float aveRain = 0;
    int monthCount = 1;
    float aveResult = 0;
    int fieldWidth;
    int outputPrecision;

    puts("This program calculates the average quarterly rainfall for a given city.");
    printf("Enter the name of the city: ");

    scanf("%s" , &cityName[50]);

    while( monthCount <= 3 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the month and average rainfall of month %d: " , monthCount);
        scanf( "%s %s %f" , &monthName[3] , &comma , &aveRain);

        monthCount = monthCount + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s" , &cityName[50]);` will try to enter the city name *at the end* of the string. Try `scanf("%s" , cityName);` and ditto for the month.

Comment: `char monthName[3];` is not long enough for a 3-letter month plus a terminator.

Comment: @WeatherVane so I have to change the 3 to a 4 instead?

Comment: Not just that: you need the months and rainfall to be arrays, such as char `monthName[3][4]` (3 for the quarter year, 4 for the string size, which is unsafe but the question says assume that 3 letters for the month are entered, ie the string does not overflow). Also an array for the rainfall `float aveRain[3]`.

Comment: ... and remember that you will index the arrays by 0, 1, and 2, so instead of setting `monthCount=1` use a loop `for(monthCount=0; monthCount<3; monthCount++) { ... `

Comment: Okay, I changed the while loop to a for loop, but it still doesn't want to go to the next month?

Comment: I suggest you research the topic of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your scanf is *bad* :

- you declare `char monthName[3]` (only **2** chars and the terminating null) and read at `&monthName[3]` **just after the end of the array** : undefined behaviour
- you try to read with `%s` in a char : as `%s` reads at least one character and writes a terminating null, here again you are writing *anywhere* with UB

You should instead :

- declare `char monthName[4]` to leave room for terminating null
- write `cr = scanf("%3s,%f", monthName, &aveRain);` in order to :

  - limit input to at most 3 characters and a null in `monthName`
  - process the comma
  - be able to control that you correctly scanned 2 fields or abort with an error message is case of problem on input

BTW the preceding scanf was also bad : you must read *in* the char array and not *after* it :

```
scanf("%49s" , cityName);
```

Comment: I changed the array monthName[3] to monthName[4] and left out the block braces at the scanf functions that call the arrays but is still doesn't want to go on to month 2?

Comment: @JanAdriaanBoshoff : you have at least another problem before. See my edit.

Comment: ok so I changed that too, but it still doesn't want to move on to the second month at runtime?

Comment: @JanAdriaanBoshoff The `\n` should not be in the input format. But now it works on my own box (even if there is still some work to meet full requirements :-) )

Comment: Finally, I got it to move on to the next months, thanks a lot!!! Now I can finally go on with it...